# Hiding Series from Embedded Plotly Plots

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, plotly

Say I have a plot embedded in an iframe like so. It is dynamically loaded. Using flask in this environment.

```
<iframe width="600" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//plotly.example.com/~account/{{ r['plot_id'] }}.embed"></iframe>
```

Is it possible to interact with the plot using the plotly.js framework? I would like to show/hide certain series based on an HTTP GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the best way is to embed the javascript, not the iframe (which is also available from plotly), and pop traces from the data list that comes in. Example:

```html
<script src="http://plotly.com/~user/<plot_id>.js"></script>
<script>
desired_trace_label = 'foo'

new_data = new Array();

for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    trace = data[i];
    if (trace.name == desired_trace_label) {
        new_data.push(trace);
    }
}

  Plotly.newPlot("div-name", new_data, layout);
</script>
```

Including the plotly.js will give you 'data', which is a list of traces, and 'layout', which is what you'd expect.

It will also attempt to make a plot in a div that doesn't exist which will raise an error.

This is rather crude, hopefully there is a cleaner solution out there somewhere.